# ResultSet .next was not called exception is thrown

Tags: java, regex, string, resultset

I have query like this

```
String sql_query = select name, display_name from parameter where id = (something);
```

After executing this query I retrieved the `ResultSet`, and then I'm trying to update the value `display_name`. It's not working and throwing an Exception

> .next was not called.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql_query);
String displayName = rs.getString(display_name);
displayName = displayName.replace("&lt;", "<");
rs.updateString(display_name,display name);
```

Comment: Did you call [`.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)?

Comment: Ya i called
Now im facing issue like resultset is only readonly .. even i tried adding CONCUR_UPDATABLE..

stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

Still im getting the issue tat Exception: Invalid operation for read only resultset: updateString

Comment: It's useful to process a ResultSet (almost any ResultSet, actually) into a List of Java objects as the very 1st thing you do with it.  In this way, you can quickly close the ResultSet, allow it to fall out of scope, and free its resources .  Doing that would solve your woes since then you'd be dealing with a List whose size you can readily determine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what it says in the error message. `ResultSet.next()` wasn't called. So call it. Not forgetting to check the return value.

Comment: Now im facing issue like resultset is only readonly .. even i tried adding CONCUR_UPDATABLE..

stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

Still im getting the issue tat Exception: Invalid operation for read only resultset: updateString

Comment: You need to add FOR UPDATE to the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve one row details, you need to call rs.next() to move the cursor to first row. To start with, cursor is positioned before the first row.
If you want to deal with multiple records, you can loop through your resultset as below. next() method returns false, so it can be used to loop till end of resultset.

```
while(rs.next()) {
  String displayName = rs.getString(display_name);
  displayName = displayName.replace("&lt;", "<");
  rs.updateString(display_name,display name);
}
```

Comment: Now im facing issue like resultset is only readonly .. even i tried adding CONCUR_UPDATABLE..

stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

Still im getting the issue tat Exception: Invalid operation for read only resultset: updateString

Comment: It might not be a problem with the query as such as you are not using any joins or 'SELECT *'. It might be the driver that is downgrading your resultset to a non-updateable one. Also, add rs.updateRow() after rs.updateString() and commit the update.

Comment: I didn't try rs.updateRow() .. I'm returning it to function and building it as a XML .. If I make < correctly and sent to XML its saying premature end of file in logs .. I'm using tat XML values in a xsl and uses it in input text box .. In tat value={@display_name}... Can u pls tell me how to resolve the prob .. Any way I could make it appear as < instead of &Lt;